# Grub2 после загрузки в Windows загружает только его

Tags: linux, grub, windows-8, altlinux

На ноутбуке Sony Vaio, установлены Windows 8 и Alt Linux. Подчёркиваю - Windows установлена **до** Alt Linux! До загрузки Windows меню Grub2 появляется без косяков. Но после загрузки в винду меню перестает появлятся - сразу грузится винда. Лечится это все загрузка на альтовскую флешку и перезагрузкой. По альтовским же мануала все настроено правильно. Думаю накосячили японцы, но с линуксом возможно всё.

Comment: И в чём японцы накосячики? У меня на VAIO TZ стояло 3 системы, GRUB работал нормально.

Comment: Убедитесь, что в винде выключен быстрый запуск / fast startup

Comment: Нет, не помогает. Только винда грузится медленнее, и всё.

Comment: Ну и в целом можно попробовать потыкать разные советы из этого раздела https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#Windows_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: Ок, попробую чуть позже...